# Can I connect Laravel on Heroku with Awardspace database?

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment

I added in ENV file on Heroku informations from Awardspace, because  I want to connect that database with Laravel project deployed on Heroku.
I am getting error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have these credentials you should put it in **settings** -> **config vars**->

```
DATABASE_URL 
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_DATABASE
DB_HOST
DB_PASSWORD
DB_PORT
DB_USERNAME
```

after added these credentials with database
you should run in `bash` `php artisan migrate`

and work fine

hopefully that is help you

Comment: Hi, I have MySQL database on Awardspace. But I tried everything and I am getting this error SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "fdb32.awardspace.net" (185.176.43.109), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: can you add this `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql2://username:password@ip.goes.here/data_base_name --app heroku-app-name`

Answer (score 0):

use this command for clear cache.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan optimize
```